# getting html form submit to call javascript (listener not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, listener

I'm trying to render the results of a query a user submits via a search bar on my website. Unfortunately, I cannot get the HTML form to call the relevant javascript file. Here's the HTML snippet containing the form:

I attempted to use implement a listener as shown below in the snippet from the JavaScript file:

```
function renderSearch(){

        const search_results = document.getElementById("search-results");
        search_results.innerHTML = "see if function is getting called.."; // this is not working
        const classN = document.getElementById('class');
        const query = {classes:classN};
        Users.find(query).project({username:1, email:1, classes:1, _id:false}).toArray(function(err,results){
            if(err) throw err;
            for(var j=0; j<results.length;j++){
                const currBuddy = results[j];
                search_results.prepend(betterBuddyDOM(currBuddy));
            }
        })
        return true;
    }

    document.getElementById('custom-search-form').addEventListener('submit',renderSearch,false);
    // $('#custom-search-form').submit(renderSearch); // also attempted using jQuery
```

Form

```
<form id="custom-search-form" class="form-search form-horizontal pull-right" name="form"> 
    <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Enter a course number" name="class" id="class">
    <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

I attempted to use implement a listener as shown above in the snippet:

search-results is an empty div at the end of my html file where I want to insert objects and renderSearch() is the function I'm using to do this. However, it does not seem to be the case that it's getting called when I submit a search. Any ideas on what could be causing this ? Would greatly appreciate any help.

EDIT:
I got it to work by changing the function signature to renderSearch(event) and including event.preventDefault() !

> Blockquote

Comment: after editing, i can see that the function "renderSearch" is being called

Comment: How so? There seems to be no change occuring on the page displayed.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it as well. It works in my case without any problem. Do you have any errors in console? Did you try to debug? Maybe there is a null object or undefined.

Comment: I'm getting different behaviors locally vs working with the snippets I've posted here. It works for me here as well. For reproducing, perhaps downloading the files I've made available in my edit, and opening the html file in a browser could yield some insight. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The same code, in the snippet the innerhtml is getting loaded with the text
"see if function is getting called..",

```js
function renderSearch(){

     const search_results = document.getElementById("search-results");
     search_results.innerHTML = "see if function is getting called.."; // this is not working
      return false;
     const classN = document.getElementById('class');
     const query = {classes:classN};
     Users.find(query).project({username:1, email:1, classes:1, _id:false}).toArray(function(err,results){
      if(err) throw err;
      for(var j=0; j<results.length;j++){
       const currBuddy = results[j];
       search_results.prepend(betterBuddyDOM(currBuddy));
      }
     })
     return true;
    }

    document.getElementById('custom-search-form').addEventListener('submit',renderSearch,false);
    // $('#custom-search-form').submit(renderSearch); // also attempted using jQuery
```

```html
<form id="custom-search-form" class="form-search form-horizontal pull-right" name="form"> 
<input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Enter a course number" name="class" id="class">
<button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i>CLick</button>

<div id="search-results"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: It does appear to be the case that the snippets work after editing to have the 'search-results' div inside the form body. However, this does not seem to solve the problem on my code...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
I got it to work by changing the function signature to renderSearch(event) and including event.preventDefault() !